# How to properly send a message to outlook with an ics file and calendar part?

Tags: c#, email, outlook, mime-types, icalendar

I need to send an email with a meeting calendar part and also with the same attached file ics. When I do it with commented lines that implement adding an attachment(as in code below) I recieve the message on Outlook without ics file but with well-displayed calendar; otherwise when attachment added I can only see the ics file and body of the message but calendar part is missing.

```
static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Console.WriteLine("Welcome");
        var client = new SmtpClient();

        Console.WriteLine("connection success");
        // Now Contruct the ICS file using string builder
        MailMessage msg = new MailMessage();
        msg.From = new MailAddress("fromemail@gmail.com", "Sender's Name");
        msg.To.Add(new MailAddress("example@outlook.com", "To Name"));
        msg.Subject = "Send mail with ICS file as an Attachment";
        msg.Body = "Please Attend the meeting with this schedule";
        StringBuilder str = new StringBuilder();
        str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VCALENDAR");
        str.AppendLine("PRODID:-//Schedule a Meeting");
        str.AppendLine("VERSION:2.0");
        str.AppendLine("METHOD:REQUEST");
        str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VEVENT");
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTART:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(+10)));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTSTAMP:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.UtcNow));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DTEND:{0:yyyyMMddTHHmmssZ}", DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(+60)));
        str.AppendLine("LOCATION: CGI");
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("UID:{0}", Guid.NewGuid()));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("DESCRIPTION:{0}", msg.Body));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("X-ALT-DESC;FMTTYPE=text/html:{0}", msg.Body));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("SUMMARY:{0}", msg.Subject));
        str.AppendLine(string.Format("ORGANIZER:MAILTO:{0}", msg.From.Address));

        str.AppendLine(string.Format("ATTENDEE;CN=\"{0}\";RSVP=TRUE:mailto:{1}", msg.To[0].DisplayName, msg.To[0].Address));

        str.AppendLine("BEGIN:VALARM");
        str.AppendLine("TRIGGER:-PT15M");
        str.AppendLine("ACTION:DISPLAY");
        str.AppendLine("DESCRIPTION:Reminder");
        str.AppendLine("END:VALARM");
        str.AppendLine("END:VEVENT");
        str.AppendLine("END:VCALENDAR");

        System.Net.Mime.ContentType contype = new System.Net.Mime.ContentType("text/calendar");
        contype.Parameters.Add("method", "REQUEST");
        contype.Parameters.Add("name", "Meeting.ics");
        AlternateView avCal = AlternateView.CreateAlternateViewFromString(str.ToString(), contype);
        msg.AlternateViews.Add(avCal);

        //Byte[] bytes = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(str.ToString());
        //var ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(bytes);            
        //msg.Attachments.Add(new Attachment(ms, contype));

        client.Send(msg);
        Console.WriteLine("Sent");
        Console.ReadLine();
    }
```

Comment: Try this link for some hints http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/27451/Send-Calendar-Appointment-As-Email-Attachment

Comment: Why do you add the same iCal data as both a MIME part and as an attachment?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Because outlook requires the MIME part whereas another web services are looking for the attachment.

Comment: @MethodMan thx, but actually the link you gave describes only how to create an attachment, but Outlook for example cannot recognize it.

Comment: Is there a web service that does not understand a text/calendar MIME message?

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Frankly I don't know, that's just a work task. But for instance when you create an event in google calendar, and then invite an outlook user, he recieves an email with a MIME part and also with an attachment file.

Comment: If Outlook can understand it, that means you can create it too. Did you try to compare the full MIME source of the message of the message sent by Outlook with your message. One thing I remember is that you need to make sure the outer message part is multipart/related if you need to include both the ICS attachment and the text/calendar part.

Comment: @DmitryStreblechenko Yes I tried, there was no difference. And also I don't see the multipart/related part in the source of google invitation.

Comment: where does the attachment reside..? can you state whether this is a winforms app or a web application..if it's a web app..then you would probably want to look at using Server.MapPath in regards to getting the correct attachment and file path..

Comment: @MethodMan It's a web app. and my attach file is represented as string just like in the example I gave above. And I can attach it to the message using the memory stream.

Comment: then at what point are you closing the memorystream.. or calling the memorystream objects WriteTo() method..?

Comment: @MethodMan actually it works with the code above you can check it out, Attachment constructor only needs a memory stream object (probably it reads stream automaticly) as ICS file is created properly. And I use "using" in my work project, this code is just a quick exemple.